# Fechar menu clicando fora dele ou no botão de abrir

Tags: jquery

Estou criando uma estrutura de menu que ao clicar no elemento, exibirá um submenu.
PRECISO que fazer isso utilizando `addClass`, pois preciso alterar a estilização dos elementos ao clicar.
Ao clicar dentro do submenu, deverá se manter aberto, mas deverá ser fechado se clicar no elemento pai do submenu ou em qualquer outro lugar fora.

Segue a estrutura

HTML:

```
   <div class="menu_btn">
      <a href="#">Botão</a>
      <div class="submenu">
         <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_btn a{
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    padding:5px;
}
.hover a{
    color:red;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:0
}
.submenu{
    display:none;
    max-width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-top:3px
}
.hover .submenu{
    display:block;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu_btn").click(function(e){
        var e=window.event||e;
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    $(document).click(function(e){
        $('.menu_btn').removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmg85dph/1/)

Comment: Você pode usar [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) e [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/), ou [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) para mostrar/esconder o menu quando clicar no botão

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q0qvd6yx/ Algumas modificações.

Comment: Earendul obrigado por responder.

Eu já tentei várias formas para executar o que preciso, porém ao clicar no elemento, preciso dar outra estilização pra ele, mudando cor da fonte, fundo, etc. Pra isso preciso utilizar o addClass.

Também preciso que o submenu fique ativo, pois no projeto, alguns submenus terão formulários e coisas do tipo. No seu Fiddle eles fecham ao clicar dentro do submenu.

De qualquer forma agradeço por ter respondido. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Mauro, tente ir melhorando e esclarecendo a *própria pergunta* quando surgirem dúvidas ou mal-entendidos. Fica mais fácil visualizar tudo ali do que espalhado em comentários.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugiro duas alterações:

- procurar por `.closest('.hover')` para saber se o click foi dentro do menu ou não

Exemplo:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).closest('.hover').length) $('.menu_btn').removeClass("hover");
});
```

- adicionar `max-width: 200px;` também no `.menu_btn`

para não interferir com o clic fora do menu.

```
.menu_btn {
    max-width:200px;
}
```

Para fazer o menu fechar também quando se clica no botão sugiro como o código em baixo. Ou seja usando

```
$(".menu_btn > a").click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.menu_btn').toggleClass("hover");
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/1zfdtk91/

#### Todo o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu_btn > a").click(function (e) {
        $(this).closest('.menu_btn').toggleClass("hover");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {    
        if (!$(e.target).closest('.hover').length) $('.menu_btn').removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

```css
.menu_btn {
    max-width:200px;
}
.menu_btn a {
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    padding:5px;
}
.hover a {
    color:red;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:0
}
.submenu {
    display:none;
    max-width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-top:3px
}
.hover .submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu_btn"> <a href="#">Botão</a>

    <div class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Removi o seu `var e=window.event||e;` pois além de estar a re-declarar a variável que a função passa é desnecessário pois o `e` que o jQuery passa para a função já está normalizado.

Comment: Sergio, obrigado por responder.
Meu maior problema nesse código todo, é que o elemento precisa fechar ao clicar fora e também no botão, mas não fechar quando tem conteúdo.
O seu código melhorou muito o que eu tinha feito, porém ainda apresenta o mesmo problema, que eu pesquisei muito hoje e não achei solução ainda.

Comment: @MauroAlves é isto que procura: http://jsfiddle.net/pmg85dph/3/ ? (ou seja fechar também quando carrega no botão)

Comment: quase isso, pois preciso que o submenu seja clicável, pois no projeto serão inseridos formulários e outros elementos que precisarão ser utilizados, então ele só tem que fechar clicando fora ou no elemento clicável inicial.

Comment: @MauroAlves ok, então se percebo bem quer assim: http://jsfiddle.net/1zfdtk91/

Comment: Sergio perfeito. Era isso mesmo que eu queria. Testei aqui no meu projeto e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.