# Como fechar um modal ao clicar fora dele?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal

Fiz um modal e preciso que ele seja fechado ao clicar fora dele ou no botão de fechar. Já tentei fazer com onblur só que não funciona, serve só para tag input. Como devo fazer?

```js
function abre() {
   document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'block';
}
function fecha() {
   document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#modal{
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  #modalcont{
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   position: relative;
   left: 35%;
   top: 20%;
   background-color: lightblue;
   text-align: center;
  }
  #close{
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 50%;
   font-size: 26px;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   text-align: center;
   right: -10px;
   top: -20px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="abre()">abra o modal!</button>
 <div id="modal" onblur="fecha()">
  <div id="modalcont">
   <a onclick="fecha()" id="close">X</a>
   <p>teste desse modal</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dei respostas parecidas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38835/129) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75133/129). Neste caso é ainda mais simples pois tens um elemento a funcionar como `overlay` onde só precisas de detectar se ouve um clique nele com

```
modal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target == this) fecha();
});
```

Exemplo:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
modal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target == this) fecha();
});

function abre() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function fecha() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#modalcont {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  left: 35%;
  top: 20%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  right: -10px;
  top: -20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="abre()">abra o modal!</button>
<div id="modal" onblur="fecha()">
  <div id="modalcont">
    <a onclick="fecha()" id="close">X</a>
    <p>teste desse modal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi direito o addeventlistener e o target

Comment: @nelson450 sabes o que faz o `addEventListener`?

Comment: Não,  e o target não conheço muito bem

Comment: @nelson450 o `addEventListener` regista no evento que queres ser avisado quando um dado evento acontece. O evento que queres "escutar" passas como primeiro argumento e a função a correr passas como segundo argumento. Faz sentido? (explico mais se até aqui compreenderes)

Comment: Sim, e o e.target?

Comment: E o onblur só funciona para formulários?

Comment: @nelson450 ok, então essa função recebe sempre um argumento, passado pelo JavaScript. Esse argumento é o evento, um objeto, que tem a propriedade `target. Essa propriedade é o elemento onde o clique aconteceu. Neste caso o `addEventListener` é associado ao `modal`, então o `this` dentro dessa função é **sempre** o modal, mas o `e.target` é o elemento (dentro do modal ou o próprio) onde o clique se deu. Faz sentido?

Comment: OK, entendi agora, obrigado